# For a subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$: $H_1/N \cong H_2/N \Rightarrow H_1 \cong H_2$. Is it true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I need to understand what can we deduce from knowing that:

> Let $G$ be a group, $H_1, H_2$ its subgroups and $N$ it's normal subgroup contained in both $H_1$ and $H_2$. Assume
>
> $H_1/N \cong H_2/N$

Can we really say that then $H_1 \cong H_2$? Or anything else related?

Comment: @Watson the dupe is slightly problematic as the accepted answer actually seems to use *equality* not isomorphy.

Comment: @Brian please see my comment above.

Comment: @quid: Ok, I agree. But isn't this answer fine: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/276976? What do you think?

Comment: @Watson yes, that answer would be a correct answer to this question.  But the question there asks for something different as written and also according to its accepted answer.  I find this way too confusing to dupe-close.

Comment: @Watson It isn't for me. I don't understand it, and it look's wrong in some way. It seems he uses $=$ instead of $\cong$. Please, don't rush to mark questions as duplicate before you actually study it in detail, this isn't the first time I see it happening.

Comment: @Watson For example, it says that $m_1 \in M_1 \Rightarrow m_1N \in M_1/N \cong M_2/N \Rightarrow (!) m_1N \in M_2/N$. How so? They are isomorphic and not equal.

Comment: @quid Could you please explain how that answer is correct? I don't care if my question is closed, honestly, I just want to understand the subject.

Comment: That answers something else. Best only read the answer by uncookedflacon which answers what you ask. It is not true that the subgroups will be isomorphic under your assumption. If  still needed I can give more details in an hour.

Comment: @quid I see. I thought Watson was referring to the comment by Babak S.

Comment: Watson is right, the answer over there by uncookedfalcon (which is the one Watson specifically linked to) also answers your question. I can reproduce it here in the comments for convenience: Let $G=\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_4$ and $H_1=\langle (0,1)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_4$ and $H_2=\langle (1,0),(0,2)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$. Then $H_1/N\cong\Bbb Z_2\cong H_2/N$ but $H_1\not\cong H_2$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: @quid IIRC there is established precedent for closing questions as duplicates simply because the already existing answers also answer  the new question, even if the question itself is slightly different, but this practice is not applied consistently.

Comment: @arctictern I assume this dupe closure was just an oversight.  To be clear I have nothing against that practice you mention, but this is not a case where it should be applied, and certainly not without explanatory comment  into a confusing dupe-target. (And there was none until I complained.) If you want to discuss this further merits, there is a meta post in the reopen thread.

Comment: @quid Ah, I wasn't aware this question was even closed. People were just too impatient to stick around and explain things to the OP I guess. Seems I'm missing some of the comment thread here too.

Answer (score 2):

The groups are not necessarily isomorphic.

A good strategy to approach such a question is to consider the simplest case first.

Thus, to make things simple let us consider $N$ is a cyclic group of prime order $p$ sitting inside a to be specified group.

For any subgroup $H$ of order $p^2$ that contains $N$, we'll have $H/N$ is of order $p$ and thus also cyclic.

Thus if what you ask about were true then all subgroups of order $p^2$ that contain $N$ would need to be isomporphic.

Is there a good reason for this? Not really. There are two types of groups of order $p^2$, the cyclic one of order $p^2$ and the direct product of two cyclic one of order $p$.

Can we find a group that contains both these types of subgroups and have non-empty intersection?

Let us take the direct product of a cyclic group of order $p^2$ with a cyclic group of order $p$. Then we certainly have cyclic subgroups of order $p^2$ and also a direct product of cyclic groups of order $p$.

For example, if we write the group elements as pairs and use additive notation, first coordinate order $p^2$ second $p$, then the group generated by $(1,0)$ that is $H_1=\{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0), \dots, (p^2 -1,0)\}$ is cyclic of order $p^2$, the one generated by $(p,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is a product of two cyclic groups of order $p$, call it $H_2$; and the intersection is  $N=\{(0,0), (p,0), (2p,0), (3p,0), \dots, (p(p-1), 0)\}$ cyclic of order $p$.

Then $H_1/N$ and $H_2/N$ are isomorphic (both cyclic of order $p$) while $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not.

Various other examples of this form could be given. (The example discussed in comments is the special case $p=2$.)